# why can't I get SDWebImage working with swift?

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

At build time, it returns an error on this line

```
typedef void(^SDWebImageNoParamsBlock)(voidvoid);
```

The error that Xcode gives me is:

> A parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition

[image: project file with error]

thanks all :)

Comment: because of a typo `voidvoid`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
typedef void(^SDWebImageNoParamsBlock)(void);
```

This a screenshot from the file you have may be you have edited it mistakenly when typing somehow

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check line number 98 you are entered  two time void

```
typedef void(^SDWebImageNoParamsBlock)(void);
```

replace this line